# I do not get why for an input above 49 like 54 there will be a <perfect square> for the fourth last output printing (out of 10)

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

```
import java.util.*;
class FindingBiggestnumber {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input positive integer");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
    
        for (int q = 1; q <= 10; q++) {
            int b = a/q;
            if ( b == q) {
                System.out.println("Perfect Square");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Perfect Square");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello. I'm trying to indicate if a number is a perfect square from the integer 1-100. I'm not allowed to use any Math function and Boolean function (they are not taught yet). Rather, we are needed to solve this using control flows/looping.

I am aware that my programme would give me 10 lines of < Not Perfect Square > or < Perfect Square >, which is wrong but I hope to solve it later.

Now, I'm facing a bug issue that I'm not sure where. When I input integers that are perfect squares, the outputs are accurate. This is likewise for other numbers. However, for an input of above 49 like 54, the fourth last row of output gives < Perfect Square > which I am absolutely puzzled by. I am aware that variable == variable is acceptable from my reading of other posts but then I don't understand what's wrong then.

Would appreciate any suggestions or feedbacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you dividing 54/7 the result is 7 and in this case b in also 7.
Your way can be improved but if you want to keep it that way you can add division remainder is equal to zero check.

```
for (int q = 1; q <= 10; q++) {
    int b = a/q;
    if ( b == q && (a%q == 0 )) {
        System.out.println(q + " Perfect Square");
    } else {
        System.out.println(q + " Not Perfect Square");
    }
}
```